# Ground loop problem

Tags: ground, ground-loop

I have two PCB : #1 and #2. #1 is receiving DC supply. #1 routes the DC supply to #2 with two wires (+5V and GND).
There is an (non differential) analogic signal which must go from #2 to #1 with another double wire. Indeed #1 has an analogic sensor.
[image: groun,d]

Should I put a GND signal in the analog wire ? If I do so, I will create a ground loop, right ? Is it bad ?

If I do not put a GND signal in the wire, I suspect the measurments will be bad due to the fact that #1 et #2 ground planes will be slightly different. Am I right ?

What is the best solution between these two options ?

Note that I am stuck with this architecture and cannot change it. I know it would be a better idea to have only one PCB or a differential analog sensor.

Thanks.

Comment: How much current is board #2 drawing (and returning on GND)?  What type of power regulators are being used?  Are you worried about DC offset or noise in analog line?  Is there a separate analog ground available with the analog input?

Comment: Aaah, real-life is full of compromises and details.  This is a common issue, with a variety of solutions depending on your level of paranoia, acceptance of interference, and the thickness of your wallet.  Please add details of all three.

Comment: Ideally avoid such a topology, make the signal differential, or digitize or modulate it at the source board.